# In boosting for regression trees, what is an example form of the final tree $\widehat{f}$?

Tags: classification, boosting, cart

In boosting for regression trees, the algorithm, for a given tree $b \in\{1,\ldots, B\}$ will fit a tree $\widehat{f^b}$ with $d$ splits to the training data $(X,r)$ where $r$ are the residuals.

Then, it updates $\widehat{f}$ by adding in a shrunken version of the new tree:

$$
\widehat{f}(x) \impliedby \widehat{f}(x) + \lambda \widehat{f^b}
$$

This doesn't quite make intuitive sense to me, because a tree is complex, with many outputs corresponding to various $x$. Therefore, by scaling it by $\lambda$, it seems to be treating it like a scalar, when it is an object. What is the correct way to think about this?

Comment: Maybe I have not quite gotten your point. But, usually, the tree is a real-valued function and you can multiply any function with a real number. Also, there are different boosted tree regression algorithms, but for some of the standard methods, it is not necessarily a shrunken version ($\lambda$ can be larger than one).

Comment: To add to @frank's comment (+1), we can use a GBM as an additive model. We make incremental updates on our expected value of  $\hat{f}{x}$ each time updating our expectation by $\hat{f^b}{x}$. In that sense, for a given $x$ we have a single output from a single base learner but we combined all of them to get our final result. (Notably we use the residuals from previous iterations as weights or as targets in our boosting procedure, if we just created independently our tree predictions and then averaged them, then we would have a random forest)